# Multiple onClicks in Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit button that redirects to another page if all the required fields are filled out.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm();redirect();" class="someClass" value="Submit" />
```

Right now when the button is clicked, it calls both functions. How do I get it to where it does not call redirect if validateForm returns false?

Here is the validateForm function if it helps:

```
function validateForm(){
    var email = document.forms["form"]["Email"].value;
    if(email == null || email == ""){
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: put the redirect in the conditional inside the validateForm function, not inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm(); return false;" class="someClass" value="Submit" />
```

Change the input to the code above. Also change your function to reflect the code below.

```
function validateForm(){
    var email = document.forms["form"]["Email"].value;
    if(email == null || email == ""){
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }else {
        redirect();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'd change that to `onlick="validateForm(); return false;"` if you don't want the default submission to occur after validation.

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

Add a onclick handler, say `validateAndRedirect`:

```
function validateAndRedirect()
{
    if(validateForm())
    {
        redirect();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add this to the button:

```
<input...onclick="validateAndRedirect()" ... >
```

This function will call `validate()`. If validation fails, will return `false`. This `false` will prevent the submit action of the button. If validation passes, it will call `redirect`.

Comment: +1 for updating the `function` name to describe what the `function` does.  If I called a `function` called `validate()` I would expect it to return a bool and not cause a redirect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first function call the next one and add this to your HTML :

```
  <input> type=button onclick="validateForm(); return false;" </input>
```

Putting 'return false' will  prevent redirection and will give time for your function to execute.

```
function validateForm(){
    var email = document.forms["form"]["Email"].value;
    if(email == null || email == ""){
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    } else
     redirect();
 }
```

Additionally, I'd recommend to abstain from putting any code in your HTML. It is considered a "bad practice". However, if you still want to put your code, it'll be more appropriate to put it in the form as an "onsubmit" action:

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

If you want the function to execute when the submit button is clicked, you can just add  an event listener in your script and an id to your button, like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.onclick = function validateForm() { /*same code as above..*/ };
```

Hope it helps!